# NextJs nested dynamic routes based on API

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, nested-routes

I am stuck with Nextjs : I need to create nested dynamic routes based on my (local) data.

Here are the routes that I would like to create :

1. **`.../cars/`            -> displays all the categories (sedan, suv, 4x4)**
2. **`.../cars/category/`       -> displays cars in the category**

   *ex : .../cars/sedan -> displays cars in the sedan category*
3. **`.../cars/category/id` -> displays the details of the car from category which has id = 1**

   *ex : .../cars/sedan/1 -> displays the details of the sedan car with id = 1*

For routes 1 and 2 it's ok but I don't know how to do the last one. Can you help me please ?

***data.js***

```
export const cars = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'sedan',
    models: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'model1',
        image: '/sedan1.jpg',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'model2',
        image: '/sedan2.jpg',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'model3',
        image: '/sedan3.jpg',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'suv',
    models: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'model1',
        image: '/suv1.jpg',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'model2',
        image: '/suv2.jpg',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'model3',
        image: '/suv3.jpg',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: '4x4',
    models: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'model1',
        image: '/4x4_1.jpg',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'model2',
        image: '/4x4_2.jpg',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'model3',
        image: '/4x4_3.jpg',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

***/cars/index.js***

```
import { cars } from '../../data';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Categories({ car }) {
  return (
    {car.map((c) => (
      <Link key={c.id} href={`/cars/${c.name}`} passHref>
        <div>{c.name}</div>
      </Link>
    ))}
  );
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: {
      car: cars,
    },
  };
};
```

***/cars/[name].js***

```
import React from 'react';

import { cars } from '../../data';

export default function CategoriesCars({ cars }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {cars.models.map((m) => (
        <p key={m.id}>{m.name}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const paths = await cars.map((c) => ({
    params: {
      name: c.name,
    },
  }));
  return { paths, fallback: false };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const { params } = context;
  const response = await cars.filter((c) => c.name === params.name);
  return {
    props: {
      cars: response[0],
    },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page folder must be:

```
pages/
 cars/
  [category]/
   [id]/
    index.jsx
   index.jsx
```

then go `/cars/sedan/2` you can access to `category` and `id` variables like this:

**cars/[category]/[id]/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Index() {
  const router = useRouter();
  // router.query.category -> sedan
  // router.query.id -> 2
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(router.query)}</div>;
}

// or 
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { params } = context;
  console.log(params); // { category: 'sedan', id: '2' }
  return {
    props: {
      cars: {},
    },
  };
};

// or if you wish use getStaticProps for SSG (with getStaticPaths)
export const getStaticPaths = async (context) => {
  const paths = cars
    .map((car) =>
      car.models.map((model) => ({
        params: {
          id: model.id.toString(),
          category: car.name,
        },
      }))
    )
    .flat(); // this is important

  return { paths, fallback: false };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const { params } = context;
  console.log(params);
  return {
    props: {
      cars: {},
    },
  };
};
```

Example: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-xsfdhv?file=pages/cars/%5Bcategory%5D/%5Bid%5D/index.jsx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can't adapt your example to my code. You are using `getServerSideProps` while I need `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`. Also when I try your directives I get an error message `Error: A required parameter (category) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for / cars / [category]`

Comment: I've edited example. You just provide path based on data. Here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-xsfdhv?file=pages/cars/[category]/[id]/index.jsx)

Comment: Thank you for your help!